# WKWebview load local html file and deep link enter to target page

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, wkwebview, deep-linking

I have a WKWebview in my app and load local .html file.
I want to use the deep link to redirect specific page.
I don't know how to do this.
 
Have you guys any idea about it? Kindly tell me a solution?

Deep link example:

> helloAPP://index.html#/article/list/123345

Code:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet WKWebView *webView;

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    self.webView = [self.webView initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds configuration:[self createWKWebApp]];
    [self.webView setNavigationDelegate:self];
    [self.webView setUIDelegate:self];
    [self.webView.configuration.preferences setValue:@YES forKey:@"allowFileAccessFromFileURLs"];
    self.webView.scrollView.bounces = NO;
    [self.webView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"www/phoneApp"]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:180];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    [self.webView loadRequest:request];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to implement the method `decidePolicyForNavigationAction` of `WKNavigationDelegate`.

```
- (void) webView:(WKWebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationActionPolicy))decisionHandler {
    if ([navigationAction.request.URL.scheme isEqualToString:@"helloAPP"]){
        // Open app page based on the url 
        decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyCancel);
        return;
    }
    decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyAllow);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should Implement `WKNavigationDelegate` in your class.

Here are some useful delegates. (**Delegates** are written in **Swift**. Same delegates are **available** in **objective C**.)

```
// MARK:- WebKit Navigation Delegate

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
            print("didstart called")
           //Here you can open url.
            UIApplication.shared.open((webView.url)!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)

    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
            print("didFinish navigation: \(navigation)")
    }

   func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
            decisionHandler(.allow)
   }
   func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didReceiveServerRedirectForProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        print("didReceiveServerRedirectForProvisionalNavigation navigation: \(navigation)")
   }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didCommit navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        print("didCommit: \(navigation)")
    }
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFail navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
        print("loading Error: \(error)")
    }
```

You can write your logic in these function.

To learn about [Visit here](https://medium.com/@kumarreddy_b/custom-scheme-handling-in-uiwebview-wkwebview-bbeb2f3f6cc1).